# dotnet run from Command Prompt

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file

I'm attempting to use a batch file to run C#.

```
dotnet run
exit
```

However, I get `dotnet run` repeatedly running as the command in Command Prompt. also, when I simply type `dotnet run` into Command Prompt, I get the same thing: `dotnet run` continually running.

When I run the same command from Git Bash, though, it works fine. Same with PowerShell. What's going on here?

Edit: I'm trying to run the project, as opposed to opening the IDE

Comment: I don't quite get what problem you're facing. I started a new project in a folder with `dotnet new console` and then run with `dotnet run` in cmd, git bash and in powershell and it ran ok, displaying "Hello world!" and then quiting

Comment: @Magnetron Just tested, and the new project works as expected with <code>dotnet run</code> in Command Prompt

Comment: Then probably is your code that have some bug.

Comment: Weird, then, that it runs fine from different terminals. I'll post an answer if it does end up being the case that it's the C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of the batch file from `dotnet.bat` or `dotnet.cmd` to a name which isn't also the name of a command!

Alternatively, include the extension with the command, `dotnet.ext` so that the interpreter doesn't search through extensions in `%PathExt%` to try to resolve the missing extension.

Preferably do both!

Comment: ...that does explain the self-opening .bat I had for a second there. Thank you!

Comment: @BenGardner, I'm happy to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

I got around the issue by running Powershell from Command Prompt and running `dotnet run` there

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're trying to start a specific project or just open an IDE, but with Windows CMD, you start processes like this `START "program-name-here"`. Most people also like to hide the CMD terminal so they run this:

`@echo off
START program-name-here`

So, as an example if I wanted to open a specific .txt with Notepad, I would do this:

```
@echo off
start notepad c:\test.txt
```

Comment: I'm trying to run the program, sorry for the ambiguity